# Resize FoldPanelBar in AuiManager

Tags: wxpython

In one of my software, I use AuiManager to manage all the different parts of the UI. Now, I start to use FoldPanelBar in one of the AuiPane. At first, I changed part of the Panel to use FoldPanelBar, and the bar is layout with others using BoxSizer. But it doesn't function correctly as the window is resized. Then I moved all the different controls in the Panel into the FoldPanelBar and make the bar the only control of the panel (No sizers anymore). But the FoldPanelBar still don't resize. Do you know why? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

After some investigation, I have solved this problem by myself. Though FoldPanelBar doesn't play well with others in a Sizer, if it's the only one in a sizer, it works. weird.